# Как просмотреть все свойства определенной функции?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как просмотреть все свойства определенной функции?

```
function blah(){} alert(blah.name); // "blah"
```

Это пример одного из свойств, а как же просмотреть все свойства?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под свойствами функции?

Comment: `for (var key in e) {
     console.log(e[key]);
     ++key;
  }`

Comment: `for in` даст только *перечисляемые* свойства. `++key` тут ни к чему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[getOwnPropertyNames](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)

```js
function foo(a){}

// Список свойств:
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(foo));

// Со значениями:
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(foo)
  .reduce((r, f) => (r[f]=foo[f], r), {}));
```

Comment: **Oh Yes! Спасибо!**